# Is there a video change detection software available?

Tags: image-processing

We have a video file from a security camera. There is a reflective object that reflects some image data but this is not clear. If we look very carefully to that reflective object, we can understand what is going on outside of that camera. Do we have a chance to substract a default scene screenshot image from every frame of the rest of the video file? That would give us the reflected objects movements' video more clearly.

## Edit

This picture shows what I need: [image]

And also this: [image]

They call this [Video-Based Change Detection](http://rvsn.csail.mit.edu/vid-match/overview/)

Comment: Are you asking about how to do this automatically (ghost cues with machine learning or [histogram equalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization) might work)? manually (there is a [question on photo stack exchange asking just this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/53945/how-to-enhance-a-reflection-in-post))? As currently this is quite broad.

Comment: I don't know if histogram equalization might work or not, but this is just the opposite of that question. Let's think that there was a woman walking behind that girl and this is a video rather than a photo. So we see just the reflection of that woman. Think that we substract that photo in the question from every frame of our imaginary video. Result would be only the woman walking behind that girl. This is result is what I need.

Comment: @JGreenwell two photos are added to make the question clearer.

Comment: Crude, home grown, background elimination can be done by subtracting out the historical average pixel value for each location.  This should suffice for mostly static views but won't scale to something like a busy airport (because the average is continually integrating noise).

Answer (score 1):

This dirty shell code got things done:

```
#!/bin/bash 

#
# READ: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/#difference

#mkdir orig-images diff-images 

fps=6

## create png files 
#ffmpeg -i orig.avi -r $fps -f image2 orig-images/image-%07d.png

cd orig-images

# get first image as default scene
for i in $(ls image-*.png); do 
    default_image=$i
    break
done
# or set default scene manually
default_image="image-0003631.png"

rm ../diff-images/*

for i in $(ls image-*.png); do 
    echo "processing: $i"
    #compare $default_image $i -compose src "../diff-images/diff-$i"
    convert $i $default_image -compose difference -composite \
           -evaluate Pow 2 -separate -evaluate-sequence Add -evaluate Pow 0.5 \
           "../diff-images/diff-$i"
done

cd ..
cd diff-images

## create movie from png files 
rm ../out.mov
ffmpeg -r $fps -start_number 3529 -i diff-image-%07d.png ../out.mov
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest scenedetect [1](https://pyscenedetect.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), a nice and updated python software

From the website, for the lazy ones

> PySceneDetect is a command-line application and a Python library for detecting scene changes in videos, and automatically splitting the video into separate clips. Not only is it free and open-source software (FOSS), but there are several detection methods available (see Features), from simple threshold-based fade in/out detection, to advanced content aware fast-cut detection of each shot.
>
> PySceneDetect can be used on its own as a stand-alone executable, with other applications as part of a video processing pipeline, or integrated directly into other programs/scripts via the Python API. PySceneDetect is written in Python, and requires the OpenCV and Numpy software libraries.
>
> Examples and Use Cases
> Here are some of the things people are using PySceneDetect for:
>
> splitting home videos or other source footage into individual scenes
> automated detection and removal of commercials from PVR-saved video sources
> processing and splitting surveillance camera footage
> statistical analysis of videos to find suitable "loops" for looping GIFs/cinemagraphs
> academic analysis of film and video (e.g. finding mean shot length)